# Apply a certain date format to all the dates listed in a table using jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table listing the dates field that are in `2015-08-27T22:38:21.0Z` format. I managed to convert them into `August 27th 2015, 3:38:21` using the `moment()` http://momentjs.com/. now i need to apply this changed format into my table.

html:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="date-time-format">
                <time datetime="{{updatedDate}}">{{updatedDate}}</time>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{address}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{details}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is the js:

```
$.each(data, function(time, format){
    var timeformat = format.date;
    moment(timeformat).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss');
});
```

Now how do i pass this:`timeformat` value into every `td` to return something like:

```
Date
September 13th 2015, 1:09:12
August 13th 2015, 1:09:12
October 13th 2015, 1:09:12
November 13th 2015, 1:09:12
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hw6wvrgL/

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: There's no code in your fiddle - and you should use a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over each `time` element:

```
$("time").each(function(){
    var date = $(this).text();
    var format_date = moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss');    

    $(this).text(format_date);
    $(this).attr("datetime", format_date);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw6wvrgL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer:

```
$("#table td.date-time-format time").map(function () {
  var originalTime = $(this).text("hello");
  $(this).text(yourTimeFormatFunctionGoesHere(originalTime));
});
```